# How can I strip certain tags from selected text inside a DIV?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**I am trying to remove certain tags from the following text when it is selected:**

```
<div id="removetags">Remove Tags</div>
<div class="thetext">
    <p>text text <b>text text</b> text text text</p>
    <p>text text text text text <i>text text</i></p>
    <p>text <u>text text</u> text text text text</p>
    <p>text text <em>text text</em> text text text</p>
</div>
```

**When a user selects part of the text, and clicks the Remove Tags button, I want it to strip the following tags from the selected area of text:**

```
$("div#removetags").click(function () {

    $("b,i,u,em").replaceWith(function() { 
        return this.innerHTML; 
    });

});
```

**Example:**

I want to only strip tags from the *selected text:

[image]

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? Do you want to remove those tags within the selection or the entire div - and let the text stay there, just without the tags, or move the matched tags content to another place?

Comment: @wiesion. I added an example.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little unclear about what your trying to accomplish, but if you want to strip html tags from elements, and put them into an element, you can use something like the code below:

```
function applyFn() {
  $('#content-div').children().each( function(){
    let txt = $(this).text();
    console.log(txt);
    $('#empty-div').append( txt );
  });
}

<button onclick="applyFn()" >Click</button>
<div id="content-div">
<p>text <h3>span text </h3></p>
</div>

<div id="empty-div"></div>
```

See the Pen [get text from html attrs](https://codepen.io/jrw2252/pen/BVmmbL/) by Ryan ([@jrw2252](https://codepen.io/jrw2252)) on [CodePen](https://codepen.io).

Comment: Hey I am only trying to remove tags from the selected text. see the new example I just added.

Comment: I basically copied the text from each child element and placed the copy in the other / empty div. Your case you just need to replace the parent container with the stripped text correct?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution i can think of is to use use `.getSelection()`'s `.containsNode()` and check it against all possible candidates within the targeted text - and when found, replace the `node` with a plain `textNode`.

```js
document.querySelector('#removetags').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  let sel = document.getSelection();
  let candidates = document.querySelector('.thetext').querySelectorAll('b,i,u,em');
  candidates.forEach(function(candidate) {
    // If you wish to only remove nodes that are selected entirely, not just partially,
    // do .containsNode(candidate, false)
    if(sel.containsNode(candidate, true)) {
      candidate.replaceWith(document.createTextNode(candidate.innerHTML));
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<button id="removetags">Remove Tags</button>
<div class="thetext">
    <p>text text <b>text text</b> text text text</p>
    <p>text text text text text <i>text text</i></p>
    <p>text <u>text text</u> text text text text</p>
    <p>text text <em>text text</em> text text text</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Objective

Basically this is what I interpreted as the Objectives:

1. Main objective is to create a text editor. Although never mentioned, having selected text then unbold, unitalicize, and ununderline (is that a real word?) by clicking a button are clear indications that you are making a text editor.
2. Select text and remove the selected inline HTML tags.

---

## Solution

Instead of just removing inline tags by selection, it would be better if you had the ability to remove ***and add*** the tags. [**execCommand API**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand) was created for developing text editors and it's very simple to use.

```
     document.execCommand(aCommandName, false, null);
```

The first parameter is the only one worth changing see [Commands](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand#Commands) for what it's capable of. The second parameter doesn't work thus it is always false. The last parameter is for commands that can pass parameters.

---

### References

- [**execCommand()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand)

  - [Commands: "italic", "bold", "underline"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand#Commands)
- [**HTMLFormControlsCollection**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormControlsCollection)

  - [HTMLElementForms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement)
  - [HTMLFormElement.elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/elements)
- **[contenteditable Attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/contenteditable)**

  - [setAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)
  - [removeAttribute()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute)

---

#### Demo

**There's a switch to place the editor into and out of edit mode**

```js
// Collect all form controls into a HTMLCollection
var x = document.forms.app.elements;

// Reference the switch
var btn = x.chx;

// Register switch to the click event
btn.onclick = editMode;

// Simple function to toggle composition mode (edit mode)
function editMode(e) {
  if (e.target.checked) {
    x.editor.setAttribute('contenteditable', true);
  } else {
    x.editor.removeAttribute('contenteditable');
  }
}
```

```css
#editor {
  font: 400 16px/1.5 Consolas;
  padding: 10px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  font: inherit;
  font-size: 24px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer
}

#chx {
  display: none
}

.switch {
  width: 9ch;
}

.switch::before {
  content: '\a0\270e';
  color: rgba(111, 111, 111, 0.33);
}

.switch::after {
  content: ' EDIT';
  color: rgba(111, 111, 111, 0.66);
}

#chx:checked+.switch::before {
  content: '\a0\270e';
  color: rgba(88, 111, 222, 0.66);
}

#chx:checked+.switch::after {
  content: ' EDIT';
  color: rgba(22, 111, 222, 1);
}
```

```html
<form id='app'>
  <fieldset id="editor">
    <p>Lorem <u>ipsum dolor sit amet</u>, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco <strong>laboris nisi ut aliquip</strong> ex ea commodo consequat.
      Duis aute <i>irure dolor in reprehenderit</i> in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, <em>sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim</em> id est laborum.</p>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset id='ui'>
    <button type="button" class="btn" onclick="document.execCommand('italic',false,null);" title="Italicize Highlighted Text"></button>
    <button type="button" class="btn" onclick="document.execCommand('bold',false,null);" title="Bold Highlighted Text"></button>
    <button type="button" class="btn" onclick="document.execCommand('underline',false,null);" title="Underline Highlighted Text"><u></u></button>

    <input id='chx' type='checkbox' class='mode'>
    <label for='chx' class='btn switch'></label>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```